# How to add checkbox to QFileDialog window in QT3?

Tags: c++, checkbox, qfiledialog, qt3

I have a problem with adding an extra checkbox to QFileDialog window. I'm talking about the same window which is opened during using `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName`.

I know how to do this in QT5, I need to make a subclass and set option `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`.

How can I do this in QT3?

Because there I don't have `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`. In QT3 there are fewer methods to choose.

Is there a similar method or maybe completely different approach to adding this checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the static methods (like `getSaveFileName`) use native dialogs, you can still subclass `QFileDialog` and use `addWidgets` method to add any widget underneath the *file types* combo box, i.e. at the bottom of the dialog.

This is a very simple example, with a checkbox:

```
#include <qfiledialog.h>
#include <qcheckbox.h>
class FileDialog : public QFileDialog
{
public:
  FileDialog() : QFileDialog(0)
  {
        QCheckBox* checkbox = new QCheckBox(this);
        checkbox->setText("Check me!!!");
        addWidgets( 0, checkbox, 0 );
  }
};
```

You can test it in a `main`:

```
#include <qapplication.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  FileDialog d;    
  d.exec();

  return a.exec();
}
```

To add a check box in the rightmost position, below the Cancel button, one could try to subclass a `QPushButton` (which is the expected type), lay out a check box in it, override the `paintEvent` with an empty implementation, so the push button won't be drawn at all (but the check box will).

```
#include <qcheckbox.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qlayout.h>
class CheckBox : public QPushButton
{
  QCheckBox* checkbox;
public:
  CheckBox(QWidget * parent) : QPushButton(parent)
  {
    QGridLayout * box = new QGridLayout(this);
    checkbox = new QCheckBox(this);
    checkbox->setText("Check this!!!");
    box->addWidget(checkbox, 0, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
  }
  void paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * ){}
};
```

This way the check box can be added as the third argument of `addWidgets`:

```
class FileDialog : public QFileDialog
{
public:
  FileDialog() : QFileDialog(0)
  {
    addWidgets( 0, 0, new CheckBox(this));
  }
};
```

and show up at the bottom right corner of the dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for help :)  I was very close to this solution, but now I have problem with setting this check box at the lower right corner, under "Type of file" label. Because when i use a layout without QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog my program crashes and quits. What should i do to move it? I haven't find solution yet.

Comment: Hey@Beond, I updated the answer, I hope the addendum solves your issue.

Comment: It added checkbox, but with distorted graphics -> https://i.imgur.com/9Scs3AZ.png How can I fix it? And if I would like to create this widget at the left corner under label the way would be the same? Because with positioning widget I have some problems. Thanks very much for help

Comment: About bad rendering: try setting some height to the checkbox (e.g. `checkbox->setFixedHeight(48);`. About putting the check box on the left side, you have to subclass `QLabel` instead of `QPushButton`, the  strategy is pretty much the same ...

Comment: Yes I know it's the same strategy, but don't know why I couldnt add this. I will try again, thanks very much for help :)

Comment: I can't set in left corner that it doesn't distorted graphics, `checkbox->setFixedHeight()` doesn't help. Is any other way to add this?